# Setting an XML route path (mysite.com/path.xml) URL route in meteor using flowrouter

Tags: xml, meteor, meteor-blaze, flow-router

I have a meteor app that uses flowrouter, and a path.xml file I want to be hosted at a http://www.mywebsite.com/path.xml extension URL.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use flowrouter to give me a /path.xml path.

Also, where do I save my path.xml file? Should it be inside the server folder?

Should my flowrouter look something like:

```
FlowRouter.route('/path.xml', {
  name: 'path'
});
```

But then where should I save my .xml file?